# lodash _.every not working for objects react

Tags: reactjs, lodash, react-bootstrap

I have to validate text input according to values in the object. i.e If I select a value in select input, I have to validate another text box. [image: Screenshot].

Here I have two values for mileage 8 . the entered vehicle capacity should be validated according to two vehicle capacity range.
vehicle capacity text box's blur event handler is :

```
 const vehicleCapacityBlurHandler = (value) => {
    const capacities = vehicleCapacityList.filter(
      (vc) => vc.mileage === mileage
    );
   const isValid = _.every(
      capacities,
      (capacity) =>
         value >=capacity.vehicleCapacityStartRange  &&
         value  <= capacity.vehicleCapacityEndRange 
      );
   console.log(isValid);
   setIsValidVehicleCapacity(true);    
 };
```

Form Code is

```
 <Form.Group className='mb-3'>
          <Form.Label>Mileage</Form.Label>
          <Form.Select
            required
            value={mileage}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setMileage(e.target.value);
              setVehicleCapacity('');
              setIsValidVehicleCapacity(null);
            }}
          >
            <option>Select Mileage</option>
            {mileageList?.map((m) => (
              <option key={m} value={m}>
                {m}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Form.Select>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className='mb-3'>
          <Form.Label>Vehicle Capacity</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            isInvalid={
              isValidVehicleCapacity === null
                ? false
                : !isValidVehicleCapacity
            }
            required
            placeholder='Enter Vehicle Capacity'
            value={vehicleCapacity}
            onBlur={(e) =>
              vehicleCapacityBlurHandler(e.target.value)
            }
            onChange={(e) => {
              setVehicleCapacity(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <Form.Control.Feedback type='invalid'>
            Please Enter valid Vehicle Capacity
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>
```

For selected input 8 in select,  If I even entered a value in between specified range, lodash every function returns false

Comment: What is the data you have for `capacities`?

Comment: `vehicleCapacityList` is an array and its value is :  `0: {id: '1', mileage: '20', vehicleCapacityStartRange: '1', vehicleCapacityEndRange: null}
1: {id: '2', mileage: '9', vehicleCapacityStartRange: '2.7', vehicleCapacityEndRange: '4'}
2: {id: '3', mileage: '8', vehicleCapacityStartRange: '5', vehicleCapacityEndRange: '6.9'}
3: {id: '4', mileage: '8', vehicleCapacityStartRange: '3', vehicleCapacityEndRange: '4.9'}
4: {id: '5', mileage: '7', vehicleCapacityStartRange: '7', vehicleCapacityEndRange: '9'}`

Comment: `capacities` value is :                                                                                                                             `0: {id: '3', mileage: '8', vehicleCapacityStartRange: '5', vehicleCapacityEndRange: '6.9'}
1: {id: '4', mileage: '8', vehicleCapacityStartRange: '3', vehicleCapacityEndRange: '4.9'}`

Comment: `vehicleCapacityEndRange` are `6.9` and `4.9`, and the value 8 is **not**. less or equal to either of them.

Comment: I want to check if entered value lies in any one of the range. If it is not in both range then result should be false. If it is in any one of the range result should be true

Comment: And it doesn't. `value >=capacity.vehicleCapacityStartRange  && value  <= capacity.vehicleCapacityEndRange` correctly returns `false` for `value = 8` and `capacity.vehicleCapacityStartRange = 5` and `capacity.vehicleCapacityEndRange = 6.9`  With simple substitution: `8 >= 5 && 6 <= 6.9` Therefore `8` lies outside the range. Same for `8 >= 3 && 8 <= 4.9`. Also, if you want to find that *any* matches, not that *all* match, then you need `_.some`. However that doesn't change the result here.

Comment: 8 is not entered value. 5.4 is entered value. 8 is selected mileage. please refer image. I am using 8 for filtering values which are having mileage 8. For that only I need here 8. mileage 8 have two capacity range.5-6.9 and 3-4.9. If the entered value is in 5-6.9 or 3-4.9 then the result shuold be true otherwise false

Comment: _.some does it. thank you sir